# Adding documents to envelopes using composite templates in DocuSign

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

I'm trying to add documents to a composite template using the docusign api and the documents aren't loading into the envelope the way I would expect it to. I currently have my code working with a test json where I add documents without using composite templates and it works perfectly. It seems the composite templates skip right over the documents however. Here's how I'm creating it:

```
{
"emailSubject": "Test Email Subject_FA",
"emailBlurb": "Test Email Body_FA",
"status": "created",
"compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "test1@yahoo.com",
                            "name": "test1",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "routingOrder": "1",
                            "roleName": "Client 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "email": "test2@gmail.com",
                            "name": "test2",
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "routingOrder": "2",
                            "roleName": "Client 2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "documents": [
                        {
                            "transformPdfFields": "false",
                            "name": "test0.pdf",
                            "documentId": "1"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
            {
                "sequence": "1",
                "recipients": {
                    "signers": [
                        {
                            "email": "test1@yahoo.com",
                            "name": "test1",
                            "recipientId": "1",
                            "routingOrder": "1",
                            "roleName": "Client 1"
                        },
                        {
                            "email": "test2@gmail.com",
                            "name": "test2",
                            "recipientId": "2",
                            "routingOrder": "2",
                            "roleName": "Client 2"
                        }
                    ],
                    "documents": [
                        {
                            "transformPdfFields": "false",
                            "name": "test1.pdf",
                            "documentId": "2"
                        }
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

}

This is a little test I'm doing so I understand this is impractical. But what I'm trying to understand is why this wouldn't add documents to the envelope. The request below does what I'm trying to do above.

```
{
"emailSubject": "Test Email Subject_FA",
"emailBlurb": "Test Email Body_FA",
"status": "created",
"documents": [
    {
        "name": "test0.pdf",
        "documentId": "1"
    },
    {
        "name": "test1.pdf",
        "documentId": "2"
    },
    {
        "name": "test2.pdf",
        "documentId": "3"
    }
],
"recipients": {
    "signers": [
        {
            "email": "test1@yahoo.com",
            "name": "test1",
            "recipientId": "1",
            "clientUserId": "1",
            "signerName": "test1",
            "defaultRecipient": "true",
            "defaultRecipientSpecified": "true",
            "routingOrder": "1"
        },
        {
            "email": "test2@gmail.com",
            "name": "test2",
            "recipientId": "2",
            "clientUserId": "2",
            "signerName": "test2",
            "routingOrder": "2"
        }
    ]
}
```

}

Does anybody know why my envelope for the composite template won't load the documents?

Thank you in advance!

**UPDATE**:

Here's my request for the composite template:

```
--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data
{                
"emailSubject": "Test Email Subject_FA",
"emailBlurb": "Test Email Body_FA",
"status" : "created",               
"compositeTemplates": [               
{                    
"inlineTemplates": [  
{ 
    "sequence": "1",    
    "recipients": 
    {                           
        "signers": [                              
        {                              
            "email": "test1@yahoo.com",    
            "name": "test1",             
            "recipientId": "1"                
        },                              
        {                              
            "email": "test2@gmail.com",  
            "name": "test2",         
            "recipientId": "2"              
        }                            
        ],                           
        "document":                  
        {                            
            "name": "test0",              
            "documentId": "1",            
            "fileExtension": "pdf"         
        }                               
    }                  
}                  
]               
},               
{                
"inlineTemplates": [   
{                     
    "sequence": "2",       
    "recipients": {         
    "signers": [            
        {                        
            "email": "test1@yahoo.com",   
            "name": "test1",          
            "recipientId": "1"
        },
        {                              
            "email": "test3@yahoo.com",  
            "name": "test3",                           
            "recipientId": "2"                               
        }
    ],                  
    "document":                                 
        {    
            "name": "test1",                             
            "documentId": "2",                           
            "fileExtension": "pdf"                       
        }                                             
    }                  
}                  
]               
}               
]           
}
--MY_BOUNDARY

Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test0.pdf"; documentid="1"

--MY_BOUNDARY

Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="test1.pdf"; documentid="2"




--MY_BOUNDARY--
```

I've adjusted my document to use name and fileDxtension, so I left out the .pdf extension on the fileName as that seems to be another method of implementing this. I've tried it both ways and had no luck.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In the request JSON you posted, you're specifying "**documents**" (plural) as a collection/array of **document** objects -- which isn't correct.  Each Composite Template item within the **compositeTemplates** array can only contain, at most, a *single* document.  This means that the JSON syntax for specifying the document within a Composite Template is as follows:

```
"document": {
    "documentId": 1,
    "name": "test1.pdf"
}
```

i.e., **document** is singular, and it's an object (not an array of objects).  Full request syntax of the 'composite templates' JSON request is shown in the answer of your prior question:
[How do I apply a template to a document using Docusign REST API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034028/how-do-i-apply-a-template-to-a-document-using-docusign-rest-api).

**RE the "UPDATE" to your question:**

In the JSON portion of the request that you've posted under "UPDATE", I notice that you have included **document** inside of the **recipients** object (which is contained within the **inlineTemplates** object) -- this is not the correct location for **document**.  Compare your JSON structure closely with the following (correct) structure, and adjust your request accordingly.  Essentially, **document** must be a peer of **inlineTemplates** -- not located within **inlineTemplates**.

```
POST https://demo.docusign.net/restapi/v2/accounts/ACCOUNTNBR/envelopes HTTP/1.1

X-DocuSign-Authentication: {"Username":"USERNAME","Password":"PASSWORD","IntegratorKey":"INTEGRATORKEY"}
Content-Type: multipart/form-data; boundary=MY_BOUNDARY
Accept: application/json
Host: demo.docusign.net
Content-Length: 162100

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "status" : "sent",
    "emailSubject" : "Test Envelope Subject",
    "emailBlurb" : "Test Envelope Blurb",
    "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "inlineTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 1,
            "recipients": {
                "signers" : [{
                    "email": "abbysemail@outlook.com",
                    "name": "Abby Abbott",
                    "recipientId": "1"
                }]
            }
        }],
        "document": {
            "documentId": 1,
            "name": "CustomerAgreement",
            "fileExtension": "pdf"
        }
    }]
}

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="CustomerAgreement.pdf"; documentid="1"

    <document bytes removed>

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="Invoice.pdf"; documentid="2"

    <document bytes removed>

--MY_BOUNDARY--
```

Comment: I didn't notice that documents section, I've fixed that but it's still not working. I made document singular and removed the square bracket on both sections. Could there be anything else I'm missing?

Comment: There might be issues with the way you're formatting the multi-part request, but I can't know for sure since you didn't post the entire request here.  If you can update your question to include the entire request (including headers and all parts -- i.e., both the JSON part and subsequent part(s) for document(s) you're sending -- omitting the document bytes is fine), then that'd increase your chance of getting good feedback here.

Comment: I updated my question and it contains the entire request if you want to review it. Thank you for assisting me by the way. It's really helpful.

Comment: I updated my answer to provide feedback about your full request.

Comment: I had just found that out a little while ago and was about to reply to this question. Thank you so much for your help, I really appreciate it.