# Create an Envelope using template and documents

Tags: docusignapi

I am trying to cover the below scenario:

Suppose company has a template which contains only signature fields and every envelope request will add new set of documents along with the template appended at the bottom.
So, the sender does not have to define fields while sending the envelope. Please provide some ideas how I can achieve this using REST API.

Thanks,
Akash

Answer (score 0):

Yes you are able to do it.  DocuSign has the ability to do composite templates:
https://www.docusign.com/developer-center/explore/features/templates

Here is an relevant discussion from another thread:
[Adding documents to envelopes using composite templates in DocuSign](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054335/adding-documents-to-envelopes-using-composite-templates-in-docusign)