# DocuSign Rest API send envelope using composite template

Tags: docusignapi, nintex-workflow, docusigncompositetmplts

I have a composite template that I use to send the following:

1. 1 document for signing
2. Another document that doesn't requiring signing, but is included
3. A document stored in a template

I am receiving the this error : Error performing web request. {
 "errorCode": "UNSPECIFIED_ERROR",
 "message": "Invalid length for a Base-64 char array or string." I have verified that the Base64 is a multiple of 4.  I think that the issue is that I don't have the right content type.  I am using Nintex and SharePoint to send the Rest API to DocuSign.

Content type: multipart/form-data;boundary=MY_BOUNDARY

```
Accept: application/json
Host: na2.docusign.net


--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
"emailSubject": "Contract Package for {ItemProperty:Title}",
"status" : "sent",
"compositeTemplates": [
{
"inlineTemplates": [
    {
        "sequence" : 2,
        "recipients": {
            "signers" : [
            {
                "email": "{WorkflowVariable:varCreatedByEmail}",
                "name": "{WorkflowVariable:varCreatedByName}",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "MI Employee",
                "routingOrder": "1",
                "tabs":
                    {"signerAttachmentTabs": [
                        {"anchorString": "/ea1/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0",
                            "tabLabel": "Scope of Work Attachment",
                            "optional": "true",
                            "tabOrder": 1},
                        {"anchorString": "/ea2/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0",
                            "tabLabel": "Pricing Attachment",
                            "optional": "true",
                            "tabOrder": 3}],
                    "textTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/ec1/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0",
                            "tabLabel": "Scope of Work Text",
                            "disableAutoSize": true,
                            "width": 550,
                            "height": 220,
                            "tabOrder": 2},
                        {"anchorString": "/ec2/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0",
                            "tabLabel": "Pricing Text",
                            "disableAutoSize": true,
                            "width": 550,
                            "height": 220,
                            "tabOrder": 4}]
                    }
            },
            {
                "email": "{ItemProperty:E_x002d_Mail}",
                "name": "{ItemProperty:Primary_x0020_Contact}",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "Vendor",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "tabs": 
                    {"fullNameTabs": [
                        {"anchorString": "/vn/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0"}]
                ,
                    "signHereTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/vs/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0"}]
                ,
                    "dateSignedTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/dvs/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0"}]
                ,
                    "initialHereTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/vi/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0"}]
                ,
                    "titleTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/vt/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0"}]
                ,
                    "emailAddressTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/ve/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0"}]
                ,
                    "textTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/va1/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0",
                            "tabLabel": "Address Line 1"},
                        {"anchorString": "/va2/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0",
                            "tabLabel": "Address Line 2",
                            "required": false},
                        {"anchorString": "/va3/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0",
                            "tabLabel": "Address Line 3",},
                        {"anchorString": "/vc/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0",
                            "tabLabel": "Vendor Name",
                            "disableAutoSize": true,
                            "width": 225,
                            "height": 32}]
                    }   
            },
            {
                "email": "{WorkflowVariable:varContractApproverEmail}",
                "name": "{WorkflowVariable:varContractApproverName}",
                "recipientId": "3",
                "roleName": "MI Approver",
                "routingOrder": "3",
                "tabs":
                    {"signHereTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/as/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0"}]
                ,
                    "dateSignedTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/das/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0"}]
                ,
                    "fullNameTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/an/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0"}]
                ,
                    "titleTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/at/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0"}]
                ,
                    "emailAddressTabs":[
                        {"anchorString": "/ae/",
                            "anchorXOffset": "1",
                            "anchorYOffset": "0"}]
                    }
            }           ]
                    }
    }               ],
    "document": {
        "documentId": 1,
        "name": "{WorkflowVariable:varContractName}",
        "documentbase64": "{WorkflowVariable:varContractBase64}"
    }
},
{
"inlineTemplates": [
    {
        "sequence" : 3,
        "recipients": {
            "carbonCopies" : [
            {
                "email": "{WorkflowVariable:varCreatedByEmail}",
                "name": "{Common:InitiatorsDisplayName}",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "MI Employee",
                "routingOrder": "1"
            },
            {
                "email": "{ItemProperty:E_x002d_Mail}",
                "name": "{ItemProperty:Primary_x0020_Contact}",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "Vendor",
                "routingOrder": "2"
            },
            {
                "email": "{WorkflowVariable:varContractApproverEmail}",
                "name": "{WorkflowVariable:varContractApproverName}",
                "recipientId": "3",
                "roleName": "MI Approver",
                "routingOrder": "3"
            }]
        }
    }],
    "document": {
        "documentId": 2,
        "name": "{WorkflowVariable:varExhibitAName}",
        "documentbase64": "{WorkflowVariable:varExhibitABase64}"
    }
},
{
    "serverTemplates": [
    {
        "sequence" : 6,
        "templateId": "D7472F81-46F9-4BEB-9017-DFAD3C0BCE83"
    }],
    "inlineTemplates": [
    {
        "sequence" : 7,
        "recipients": {
            "signers" : [{
                "email": "{WorkflowVariable:varCreatedByEmail}",
                "name": "{Common:InitiatorsDisplayName}",
                "recipientId": "1",
                "roleName": "MI Employee",
                "routingOrder": "1"
            },
            {
                "email": "{ItemProperty:E_x002d_Mail}",
                "name": "{ItemProperty:Primary_x0020_Contact}",
                "recipientId": "2",
                "roleName": "Vendor",
                "routingOrder": "2",
                "tabs": {
                "textTabs": [
                {
                "tabLabel": "VendorName"}]}
            },
            {
                "email": "{WorkflowVariable:varContractApproverEmail}",
                "name": "{WorkflowVariable:varContractApproverName}",
                "recipientId": "3",
                "roleName": "MI Approver",
                "routingOrder": "3"
            }
            ]
        }
    }],
    "document": {
        "documentId": 4,
        "name": "CCare_Pledge.pdf"
    }
}]
}

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="{WorkflowVariable:varContractName}";     documentid="1"

<document bytes removed>

--MY_BOUNDARY--
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="{WorkflowVariable:varExhibitAName}";     documentid="2"

<document bytes removed>

--MY_BOUNDARY--
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="CCare_Pledge.pdf"; documentid="4"
```

Link to base64-
http://www.mihomes.com/corp/vit/Base64.txt

Comment: The error message you quote is quite clear, yet you have removed the base-64 parts of the message, so we cannot see whether it is reasonable.

Comment: So if the thought is that the error is being thrown by the documentbase64 section of this API call, please ensure the provided b64 encoded string is one contiguous line. Should not include any line breaks.

Comment: I have tried removing the line breaks and I still receive the same error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In looking at the request you've posted, a few things jump out at me:

First, you've incorrectly specified the boundary separator for the part that specifies **documentid=2** as "*--MY_BOUNDARY--*"

```
--MY_BOUNDARY--
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="{WorkflowVariable:varExhibitAName}";     documentid="2"
```

By including the *--* at the end of this boundary string, you're indicating the end of the multipart message, so it's quite possible that DocuSign is not reading any of the request content that follows this string.  I'd suggest changing this to "*--MY_BOUNDARY"*

Secondly, you're specifying document bytes multiple times for two of the documents (documentid=1 and documentid=2) -- once as part of the **document** object (using the **documentbase64** attribute) in each Composite Template, and again in the additional parts of the multipart request.  I'd suggest removing the **documentbase64** attribute from the **document** object of each Composite Template object -- it's not needed if you're specifying the document bytes in additional parts of the multipart message.

Next, if **CCare_Pledge.pdf** is the first document contained in the Template you're using, then you should remove the **document** attribute (object) from that Composite Template object:

```
"document": {
    "documentId": 4,
    "name": "CCare_Pledge.pdf"
}
```

And also remove the final part of the request:

```
--MY_BOUNDARY--
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="CCare_Pledge.pdf"; documentid="4"
```

This is not needed because the document's coming from the Template itself, so you don't need to specify document info in the request.

Finally, make sure that your request ends with the correct boundary terminator string:

```
--MY_BOUNDARY--
```

(The answer to this [other post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20054335/adding-documents-to-envelopes-using-composite-templates-in-docusign) shows a good example of overall request structure with regard to boundary separators.)

Once you've implemented these suggested changes, your request structure should look like this:

```
--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/json
Content-Disposition: form-data

{
    "emailSubject": "Contract Package for {ItemProperty:Title}",
    "status" : "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
        {
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence" : 2,
                    "recipients": {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            ],
            "document": {
                "documentId": 1,
                "name": "{WorkflowVariable:varContractName}"
            }
        },
        {
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence" : 3,
                    "recipients": {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            ],
            "document": {
                "documentId": 2,
                "name": "{WorkflowVariable:varExhibitAName}"
            }
        },
        {
            "serverTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence" : 6,
                    "templateId": "D7472F81-46F9-4BEB-9017-DFAD3C0BCE83"
                }
            ],
            "inlineTemplates": [
                {
                    "sequence" : 7,
                    "recipients": {
                        ...
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="{WorkflowVariable:varContractName}"; documentid="1"

<document bytes removed>

--MY_BOUNDARY
Content-Type: application/pdf
Content-Disposition: file; filename="{WorkflowVariable:varExhibitAName}"; documentid="2"

<document bytes removed>

--MY_BOUNDARY--
```