# DocuSign Status Code TAB_REFERS_TO_DOCUMENT_NO_TABS_ALLOWED?

Tags: docusignapi

I am currently using the REST api to create an envelope containing a document and a template which I have already set up in Docusign. I get the following error on the web request and can't find this error on the status code/error list provided by DocuSign to try debug the issue. Their support person suggests I ask here..

TAB_REFERS_TO_DOCUMENT_NO_TABS_ALLOWED -- The Tab refers to a document that does not allow tabs.

Has anyone experienced this?

Edit:

The issue appears to be related to the document section.

```
{
    "emailBlurb":"Test Email Body",
    "emailSubject": "Test Email Subject",
    "status" : "sent",
    "compositeTemplates": [
    {
        "serverTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 1,
            "templateId": "b1eccee3-9c00-4cb2-8d30-0400d51dcfe0"
        }],
        "inlineTemplates": [
        {
            "sequence" : 2,
            "recipients": {
                "signers" : [{
                    "email": "usera@bah.com",
                    "name": "usera",
                    "recipientId": "1",
                    "roleName": "Producer"
                }]
            }
        }],
        "document": {
            "documentId": 1,
            "name": "Test.docx",
           "documentBase64":"[bytesremoved]",
           "fileExtension":"docx"
        }
    }]
}
```

Comment: Firstly, if the DocuSign support doesn't even know what their own error codes are, and refers you to StackOverflow, you might want to chat to someone else. I've used DocuSign a few times, and I've never seen that error. Tabs refer to the placeholders on the template you create - is there a reason they don't want you defining placeholders on that template?

Comment: I removed my placeholders off the template e.g. signature and don't get that error anymore, but I obviously want the placeholders there, so not sure what the alternative is. I'm using a composite template.

Comment: The error almost sounds like it's still referencing tabs that dont exist - possibly the issue? Either way, I found their technical support is good, so you might want to chat to someone else.

Comment: If you can post the full API request (JSON) that's resulting in this response, that would be helpful. Hard to speculate on the reason for the error without seeing the request itself.

Comment: I'm using a Nintex web request so this seemed like the easier way but think I'm rather going to write a custom web service for this.

Comment: I made the web service and added the JSON above and the file in a stream, there was no error and I got a document to sign however I can see this document is just the template and not the actual document that I want to sign with a template applied to it.

I then went back to Postman client, i.e. back to the beginning again and tested out the concept again. Removed the "documentBase64":"[bytesremoved]" from the JSON body (raw) and uploaded the file in the body (binary). I have the same result. I get a file to sign but it's clearly the template and not the actual file that I'm viewing.

Answer (score 1):

So you have a template on the server, with a document as part of the template?

But you want the envelope to use a different document with the template, yes?

It is my understanding that the `documentId` in the document section of the composite template must match the `documentId` used in the template if you want the document to be substituted for the template's document.

So check the definition of the template. Did you create the template programmatically or did you use the web browser DocuSign app? If the latter, then note that the first document in a template is not always given an id of 1.

Comment: I have a template which I created with the DocuSign app that is residing under the templates section on Docusign. I now want to send my document which I have grabbed from another location and apply that template to it before it gets sent to the user to sign.
I was following this sample in example 1

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034028/how-do-i-apply-a-template-to-a-document-using-docusign-rest-api

Comment: @Sheree, as I suggest above, look at the definition of the template. Use method https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Templates/Templates/get/ You can use the apiexplorer.docusign.com for this. See what the documentID is in the template.

Comment: Where do I find the documentId of the document that I used to create the template from within DocuSign? Will it keep the signing tabs if I replace it with my document?

Comment: Ok will check it out

Comment: Thanks that seems to have worked! Appreciate the assistance :)