# Using composite templates with initials here

Tags: docusignapi, docusigncompositetmplts

This is with the Rest api. I'm using composite templates, adding my signers in a corresponding inline template. Can inline templates also be used for Initials Here?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes you can create Initial Here tabs using inlineTemplates. Here is a sample request

[POST](https://docs.docusign.com/esign/restapi/Envelopes/Envelopes/create/) /v2/accounts/{accountId}/envelopes

```
{  
   "emailSubject":"Please complete the following forms",
   "status":"created",
   "compositeTemplates":[  
      {  
         "serverTemplates":[  
            {  
               "sequence":"1",
               "templateId":"A71FC458-E234-42FF-9385-E672C4EFD436"
            }
         ],
         "inlineTemplates":[  
            {  
               "sequence":"1",
               "recipients":{  
                  "signers":[  
                     {  
                        "name":"Jane Doe",
                        "email":"JaneDoe@xyz.com",
                        "roleName":"RoleOne",
                        "recipientId":"1",
                        "routingOrder":"1",
                        "tabs":{ 
                              "signHereTabs": [
                                {
                                  "documentId": "1",
                                  "pageNumber": "1",
                                  "xPosition": "70",
                                  "yPosition": "52"
                                }
                                ],
                                "initialHereTabs": [
                                {
                                  "name": "Initial Here",
                                  "documentId": "1",
                                  "pageNumber": "1",
                                  "xPosition": "109",
                                  "yPosition": "170",
                                }

                            ]
                        }
                     }
                  ]
               }
            }
         ]
      }
   ]
}
```

Comment: I did what you said and it worked. But I also have the signing tabs and the initial tabs in my template and I have different anchor tags, one was Buyer1 and the other Buyer1Initials. I set the signer's role as Buyer1. Without stating that there was an initial tab in the inline template, it worked. I'm confused about why it worked.

Comment: This answer might have more information you are looking for http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20034028/how-do-i-apply-a-template-to-a-document-using-docusign-rest-api